# Select every row, which contains a specific value from a datasetHow to select rows from a dataset in Mathematica?

Tags: database, select, wolfram-mathematica, criteria

How can I select every row, which contains a specific value from a dataset? The selecting criteria I want to you use, is if it contains a specific value in one of his cells.
I'm getting mad exploring the documentation center and this forum. I'm also getting mad because I know perfectly that is a common job we are supposed to do with mathematica if we want to work with datasets, but unfortunately I have no clue.

for example, this is a small database that I created for my question

```
{{"user_id;language;country;destination;search_for;criteria"},
{"1; it; italy; greece; hotel; 3*, parking, pool"},
{"1; it; italy; greece; appartment; parking, pool"},
{"2; en; usa; usa; hotel; 5*, golf"},
{"3; fr; france; spain; hotel; 4*, pool, shuttle"},
{"3; fr; france; spain; hotel; 3*, shuttle"},
{"3; fr; france; france; hotel; 3*, 4*, shuttle, pool"}, 
{"3; fr; france; france; hotel; 4*, shuttle, pool, parking"}, 
{"4; en; usa; bahamas; hotel; 4*"},
{"4; en; usa; mexico; hotel; 4*"},
{"5; en; uk; spain; hotel; shuttle"},
{"5; en; uk; spain; hotel; shuttle, pool"}, 
{"6; de; germany; italy; appartment; pool, parking"}, 
{"6; de; germany; italy; hotel; pool, parking"}, 
{"6; de; germany; greece; appartment; pool"},
{"7; fr; switzerland; france; hotel; 4*},
{"8; en; canada; usa; hotel; 4*, SPA"},
{"9; de; switzerland; italy; hotel; 4*, SPA"},
{"9; de; switzerland; italy; hotel; 4*, pool, fitness"}, 
{"10; it; italy; italy; appartment; parking, petfriendly"}}
```

please don't care to the poor display I did.

my point is, for example:
I have to Select every rows which contains in the column "criteria" the word "pool"
this is only an example of database. the one which I want want to work it is already in a ".mx" file, and I imported in the following way:

```
SetDirectory@SystemDialogInput["Directory"];
FileNames[]
mydata = Import["main.mx"]
```

and it's showed as a, [proper table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkjJN.jpg) (like excel)

Answer (score 3):

Call your list `lst` and use

```
Pick[lst, StringContainsQ[Flatten[lst], "pool"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data = {
   {"user_id;language;country;destination;search_for;criteria"},
   {"1; it; italy; greece; hotel; 3*, parking, pool"},
   {"1; it; italy; greece; appartment; parking, pool"},
   {"2; en; usa; usa; hotel; 5*, golf"},
   {"3; fr; france; spain; hotel; 4*, pool, shuttle"},
   {"3; fr; france; spain; hotel; 3*, shuttle"},
   {"3; fr; france; france; hotel; 3*, 4*, shuttle, pool"},
   {"3; fr; france; france; hotel; 4*, shuttle, pool, parking"},
   {"4; en; usa; bahamas; hotel; 4*"},
   {"4; en; usa; mexico; hotel; 4*"},
   {"5; en; uk; spain; hotel; shuttle"},
   {"5; en; uk; spain; hotel; shuttle, pool"},
   {"6; de; germany; italy; appartment; pool, parking"},
   {"6; de; germany; italy; hotel; pool, parking"},
   {"6; de; germany; greece; appartment; pool"},
   {"7; fr; switzerland; france; hotel; 4*"},
   {"8; en; canada; usa; hotel; 4*, SPA"},
   {"9; de; switzerland; italy; hotel; 4*, SPA"},
   {"9; de; switzerland; italy; hotel; 4*, pool, fitness"},
   {"10; it; italy; italy; appartment; parking, petfriendly"}};

cols = First[StringSplit[First[data], ";"]];

d2 = Flatten[StringSplit[#, "; "] & /@ Rest[data], 1];

sel = Select[d2, StringMatchQ[Last@#, "*pool*"] &];

Grid[Prepend[sel, cols], Alignment -> Left, Frame -> All, Spacings -> {1, 1}]
```

[image]